# Why does 'gradle run' only seem to work from the Windows command line?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I am using Windows 7 and I am using the IntelliJ plugin for gradle.

Here is the simple code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Input a string: ");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = in.next();

        System.out.println("Method 1: " + doesStringHaveUniqueCharsMethod1(input));
    }

    private static boolean doesStringHaveUniqueCharsMethod1(String input) {
        if (input.length() > 256) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++) {
                if (i != j && input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(j)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Here is the build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "Solution"

run {
    standardInput = System.in
}
```

It works great when I run `gradle -q run` from the command line but when I run the "run" task with the IntelliJ gradle plugin, I get the following output:

```
12:22:45 PM: Executing external task 'run'...
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:run
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
    at Solution.main(Solution.java:9)
Input a string: :run FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.082 secs
Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
12:22:49 PM: External task execution finished 'run'.
```

Answer (score 0):

**This Might Help ->**

```
 apply plugin: 'java'



 task runTask(type: JavaExec) {
 main = 'Solution'
 classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
 standardInput = System.in
 }

 defaultTasks 'runTask'
```